# FastAPI/Pydantic in a project with MyPy

Tags: python, mypy, pydantic, fastapi

Im currently working through the fastAPI tutorial, and my environment is setup with black, flake8, bandit and mypy.  Everything in the tutorial is working fine, but I keep having to # type: ignore things to make mypy cooperate.

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: str = None
    price: float
    tax: float = None


@app.post("/items/")
async def create_items(item: Item) -> Item:
    return item
```

Mypy then errors:

```
 ❯ mypy main.py                                                                                                                                                                                                 [14:34:08]
main.py:9: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "str")
main.py:11: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "float")
```

I could # type: ignore, but then I lose the type hints and validation in my editor.  Am I missing something obvious, or should I just disable mypy for FastAPI projects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Optional`:

```
from typing import Optional

class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: Optional[str] = None
    price: float
    tax: Optional[float] = None
```

That tells `mypy` that the value should be of that type but `None` is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mypy it could complain with type declarations like:

```
tax: float = None
```

With an error like:
Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "float")
In those cases you can use Optional to tell mypy that the value could be None, like:

```
tax: Optional[float] = None
```

In the above code, 
Check out this video, its been explained in this one 
[Base Model explained here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h81xGNXySuI)